# mongodb using where with different column names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, where-clause

I m having a four records in a table out of which one is having a different column name (**"usernm"** below)-

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583d67ec8a2a25b70f6af482"), "username" : "pradyut", "password" : "hello123" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583d68328a2a25b70f6af483"), "username" : "google", "password" : "google123" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583d71902a7b4dfc334d1ab4"), "usernm" : "praddy", "password": "google123" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583d71b82a7b4dfc334d1ab5"), "username" : "some", "password": "some123" }
```

The below **where** command is not working

```
db.users.find({$where:"this.username.length>=2"});
```

and throwing the error  -

```
 Error: error: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "TypeError: this.username is undefined :\n_funcs3@:1:24\n",
"code" : 139
}
```

On removing the **"usernm"** column, it works fine

```
db.users.remove({usernm:"praddy"});
```

Comment: Can you ignore the records not having **usernm** key and only check for **username** ?

Comment: @MohammadAmin Yes please ignore

Comment: Then Murat K.'s answer should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the field exists and query it afterwards e.g.

```
.find({"username" : {$exists:true}, $where :"this.username.length >= 2"})
```

Comment: This is correct but it wouldn't actually solve the OP's problem, since maybe his record is the one having "usernm" not "username".

Comment: @MohammadAmin I see. One second let me check something